# boost::object_pool::construct() in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, boost

using boost 1.47(x86) at vc2008

```
#include<boost/pool/object_pool.hpp>
class A
{
private:
    friend class boost::object_pool<A>;  //to prevent alloc other ways (ex> new A;)
    A(int a, int b){ aa = a; bb = b}
    int aa;
    int bb;
};

void main()
{
    boost::object_pool<A> pool;
    A* pa = pool.construct();   //error "No appropriate default constructor available"
}
```

The default constructor does not exist, how do I create a class using **boost::object_pool** ?

Answer (score 0):

```
A* pa = pool.construct(1, 2);  // set required values here
```

According to Boost documentation: object_pool

t.construct(???), returns ElementType*. ElementType must have a constructor matching ???.

AFAIK, up to 4 parameters are supported by this magic.

Answer (score 0):

To use an object_pool to allocate objects and pass parameters to their constructor, use its `construct` method instead of its `malloc` method, as @alex-f indicated. In your case:

```
A* pa = pool.construct(1, 2);  // The parameters are passed to A's constructor
```

The issue is that although the `boost::pool` library is header-only, and thus doesn't need to be built per se, the `construct` method needs to be declared and defined to accept arbitrarily many parameters. Since shipping `boost::pool` with `construct` method declarations that accept up to 100 parameters would make the headers exceedingly long and slow down compilations, the solution they chose seems to be that a one-time script `boost/pool/detail/pool_construct{_simple}.{sh,bat}` needs to be run that generates `construct` definitions that support however many parameters are needed. On Linux distributions where `boost::pool` is available as a package, the script has been run for you. On Windows or when using the library from a repository, if you don't run the script, the construct method will not be available at all.

The `pool_construct{_simple}` script requires a preprocessor engine called `m4`. The easiest way I found to run the `pool_construct{_simple}` script on Windows is using to run `bash` from the WSL and run:

```
sudo apt install m4
./boost_dir/boost/pool/detail/pool_construct_simple.sh 10
```

You can, of course, change the argument if your constructors take more than 10 parameters. Running the commands above creates a `bool/pool/detail/pool_construct_simple.ipp` and then the regular include file for `boost::pool` get support for the `construct` method.

Running the non-simple `pool_construct` script creates definitions such that each parameter is regular, `const`, `volatile`, or `const volatile`. So for 10 parameters there are 4^10 methods to write that take 10 parameters. This causes the script to run for a long time, use a lot of memory, and generate a ~700MB `pool_construct.ipp` file. I found that the way my project is defined, the huge file doesn't even make the `construct` method available to my code.